# Objective C Maths not returning correct value

Tags: ios, objective-c, c, math, floating-point

I'm trying to do a percentage sum in objective c

10 / 100 * 75 = 7.5

```
float x = ((10 / 100) * 75);
```

This returns 0.000000.

If I use a much bigger number instead of 10, for example 1024

1024 / 100 * 75 = 768

```
float x = ((1024 / 100) * 75);
```

It returns 750.000000.

I'm lost on this one, not sure if the math is wrong, the variable type needs changing from float, or if there's an objective c inbuilt percentage function I could use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a need to study the "C" language.

Incorrect:

```
float x = ((10 / 100) * 75);
```

Says: Take the integer value 10, divide it by the integer value 100: the result is 0. Then multiple by the integer value 75: the result is 0. Then convert to a float, the result is 0.

Correct:

```
float x = (10.0 / 100.0) * 75.0;
```

Says: Take the floating point value 10, divide it by the floating point value 100: the result is the floating point value 0.1. Then multiple by the floating point value 75: the result is 7.5.

The ".0" makes the number a floating point number.

Comment: As @Jody states it is not necessary to specify each number as a floating point number but it will help avoid errors.

Answer (score 2):

You are performing integer math, which will never result in a floating point result.
If you want floating point math, use floating point numbers.

Math operations involving at least one floating point number, will result in a floating point number.

So, either cast one of the numbers...

```
float x = ((10 / (float)100) * 75);
```

or add a 'decimal part' to the number, making it a floating point number...

```
float x = ((10 / 100.0) * 75);
```

NOTE: leaving aside the difference that 100.0 is actually a double... which is probably another common "google-able" question...